# Cannot display all choices in chatbot iframe(MS btoframework) when opened in IE

Tags: html, css, iframe, botframework, chatbot

I have developed a chatbot using microsoft botframework and its URL is used in Iframe in a webpage. The chatbot has multiple choices for questions. When I use the bot in Chrome all the choices are visible but in IE only the first choice is visible. I tried increasing the margin-bottom, flex css elements but didnt work. Please help me to display all choices. Here is an image of bot from Chrome and IE
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the part of the code that should be displaying the choices

Comment: if (String(session.privateConversationData.userStatus)==String('200'))
{
 builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Hi '+session.privateConversationData.userName+'. Please confirm that your user account is '+session.privateConversationData.userID+' and you would like to proceed.', "YES|NO", {listStyle: builder.ListStyle["button"]});
 }

Comment: The code in chatbot is perfectly fine as using the azure deployed URL directly in chrome and IE has no problem, once I embed in html, it is not working in IE

Comment: Looks like someone else had same issue as you this might help https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/674

Comment: that thread is closed due to inactivity...

Comment: Yes but can you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: I've tried reproducing your issue, but using the webchat embedded iframe in IE isn't causing any problems when trying. Can you post your html and bot code so we can eliminate all errors (edit your original question)? Be sure to replace any secrets/keys with generic text.